# URLEncode variable Parsing from String to Array as3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, parsing

Ok! I have a flashVar variable that is coming into Flash, its URL encoded but I have already decoded it. My problem is I want the set of variables to be pushed into an array.

Let's say the variables are

> "&text0=Enter Text...&size0=18&font0=Arial&color0=0&rotation0=0&y0=360&x0=640&text1=Enter
>   Text...&size1=18&font1=Arial&color1=0&rotation1=0&y1=360&x1=640"

and so on...

What I want is the variables to go into an array like

```
myArray[0].text = Enter Text...
myArray[0].size = 18]
myArray[0].font = Arial
myArray[0].color = 0
myArray[0].rotation = 0
myArray[0].y = 360
myArray[0].x = 640
myArray[1].text = ...........
.............................
.............................
myArray[n].text = ...........
```

I think there must be some way to do this. Most probably I'm thinking regular expression, but I'm pretty bad at regular expression. Please some help would be *very very* appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to decode your query string, just use the URLVariables object - it will do all the decoding for you. Then iterate over its dynamic properties to create your array.  Use a RegExp to find the index numbers at the end of your variable keys:

```
function parseURLVariables( query:String ) : Array {
    var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables (query);
    var arr:Array = [];
    for (var key : String in vars) {
        var splitIndex : int = key.search(/[0-9]+$/);
        var name:String = key.substr (0,splitIndex);
        var indexNumber:int = parseInt ( key.substr(splitIndex));
        arr[indexNumber] ||= {};
        arr[indexNumber][name] = vars[key];
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

Since your query string starts with a an ampersand, you might have to use `parseURLVariables ( myString.substr(1))`, otherwise the URLVariables object will throw an error, complaining that the query string is not valid (it has to be url encoded, and start with a variable key).

Answer (score 0):

you may use split method of string to something like this;

```
var astrKeyValue: Array = url.Split( "&" );
```

in this way each value in `astrKeyValue` is string keyvalue ( for example `font1=Arial` )
after than you may split each item with "=" and will get pair key and value ( for key - font1 and for value - arial)
so this code maybe will work for you

```
var str = "text0=Enter Text...&size0=18&font0=Arial&color0=0&rotation0=0&y0=360&x0=640&text1=Enter Text...&size1=18&font1=Arial&color1=0&rotation1=0&y1=360&x1=640"
var a : Array = str.split( "&" );
var newArr: Array = new Array()
for each ( var str1 in a )
{
    var t: Array = str1.split( "=" );
    newArr[ t[0] ] = t[1];
}

trace( newArr.text0 ) // -> Enter Text...
```

Comment: You should look at the URLVariables class - it might save you some time in the future. Also: OP wants to parse these values into an indexed array - `text0` will not suffice.  You should read the questions more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you from me,

```
//your string data should be like this, there should be a seperate seperator (i've used pipe sign |) for each element which will be converted to an object and then pushed to the array
var strData:String = "text=Enter Text...&size=18&font=Arial&color=0&rotation=0&y=360&x=640|text=Enter Text...&size=18&font=Arial&color=0&rotation=0&y=360&x=640";

var myArray:Array = new Array();
var _tmpArr:Array = strData.split("|");

//populating the array
for(var i:int=0;i<_tmpArr.length;i++)
{
    myArray.push(strToObj(_tmpArr[i]));
}
trace(myArray.length);

// coverts chunk of string to object with all key and value in it
function strToObj(str:String):Object
{
    var obj:Object = new Object();
    var tmpArr:Array = str.split('&');

    for (var i:int = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++)
    {
        var _arr:Array = String(tmpArr[i]).split('=');
        var key:String = String(_arr[0]);
        var val:String = String(_arr[1]);
        obj[key] = val;
        trace(key+" = "+val);
    }
    trace("----");
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Dude, I'm not allowed to used "|" separators.

Comment: That was biggest problem in the example. To split the strings into arrays without having a separator to split it with, @weltraumpirat's function works. Thanks for taking the time to help.